# How to change the font size in colaboratory (colab research)?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am finding the font size in colaboratory (colab research) too small. Is there a way to change the font size for code editor? I tried the "Preferences" but don't see an option for font size.

Comment: How about increase browser font size, e.g. Ctrl + Plus

Comment: answer by JorSan is the best Tools> Settings> Editor> Font Size

Answer (score 4):

The font size cannot be adjusted in Colab itself, but most if not all modern browsers allow you to adjust the font size site-wide. For most browsers, pressing `Ctrl +` (on windows/linux) or `Cmd +` (on Mac/OSX) will do this.

Answer (score 4):

In case of chrome browser, you can install the extension called 'advanced font setting'. Then  change font type or size of the fixed-width fonts with this plug-in.

In case of other browsers like Firefox, similar approaches may be possible.

[image: plugin capture]

Comment: I tried doing the same but font size in colab is same as it was before.

Comment: Sorry, I found that only output window font can be changed with this method.

Comment: someone recommended this site. if you want I think we can change font size with this custom style. https://userstyles.org/styles/168225/dark-theme-for-google-colab-ide

Answer (score 4):

In colab Menus: Tools> Settings> Editor> Font Size

Comment: As of Dec 2021, this does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2023, this works again: In colab Menus: Tools> Settings> Editor> Font Size.

There are also some other tricks that you can do in code as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/u_bfhc2Z6vg?si=z3SjMFmff2Zrz7JT

```
from IPython.display import HTML
shell = get_ipython()

def adjust_font_size():
  display(HTML('''<style> 
    body {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  '''))

if adjust_font_size not in shell.events.callbacks['pre_execute']:
  shell.events.register('pre_execute', adjust_font_size)
```